# Zooming on Chrome causes CSS positioning issues

Tags: css, google-chrome, resize, positioning, zooming

When I zoom in and out on my webpage in Google Chrome, items that are precisely positioned in relation to one another will change position. This causes many problems: For example, at specific zoom levels a div will overlap its containing div just enough to hide a border. Similarly, sometimes a 100% marker will not precisely line up with the 100% point.

Is there any way I can ensure that the positioning of the items in relation to each other will not change when the page is zoomed in or out?

Comment: can u post your code in jsfiddle.net or give link of your site

Comment: If you think you have found a bug, post it at http://crbug.com and then you have a chance if it being fixed.

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223074/absolute-html-layout-is-broken-when-zooming/28223433#28223433

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use em positioning which will reposition and size based on the font size. So when people do like control + or command + then the page will auto resize. Here is a page about elastic layouts. Hope this helps.

http://v1.jontangerine.com/log/2007/09/the-incredible-em-and-elastic-layouts-with-css

Comment: Of all of the sites giving beginner tips on CSS, this answer is the first place that I have found to even mention that the zoom problem is based on em.  I just assumed all of the pages that have good zoom scaling were just made by someone who knew advanced tricks, and not that it was so simple.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the positive review!

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, using a `left:` px value and a `top:` px value compared to left/bottom right/bottom or right/top seems to do the trick. This applies to both Chrome and FF, can't comment on IE.

For example:

```
#my-element
{
  list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 54px;
    top: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old topic, I stumbled upon this problem. Fixed by adding wrapper containers to the "elusive" elements. So before trying to fix the element css maybe check and make sure the content wrappers first.